# Querying Access 2007 multi-valued fields using ODBC

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have an Access 2007 database that uses the "Attachment" datatype (new in Access 2007) for one of its field.  This field is a magical "multi-valued" field that can contain several attachments.

I would like to be able to easily see the contents of this field, for all the rows in the database, using a single ODBC query.  Ideally, each row of the original table should be exactly one row, and I'd like all the attachments returned as a single database cell.  In a perfect world, it would be possible to reinsert that set of attachments into another table using a single INSERT INTO query.

I think that might be a tall order, so if I have to, I'd settle for:

- An SQL query that tells me the number of attachments in a given attachment field

or worst case:

- An SQL query that tells me whether or not the attachments in a given row are empty or not.

I can't seem to find any good docs about multi-valued fields around on the net.  Perhaps they're too new.

Thoughts?

(P.S. Don't bother telling me that multi-valued fields are evil.  I already know.  I'm not the one who made the database.)

Comment: See this article 'Multivalued datatypes considered harmful' (http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/07/18/multivalued_datatypes_access/print.html)... oh, sorry, you said *don't* tell me. Ignore ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use ADO then connect to the data source *without* using `OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True` in the connection string and query the column: you should get a column of type `adLongVarWChar` (i.e. `MEMO`) where the value is the file names delimited by semicolon characters. Therefore, getting a list of files will merely involve a simple parse.

It *may* be possible to get the attachments using ADO but I've yet to see it done. Using `OLEDB:Support Complex Data=True` means you will get a column of type `adIDispatch` i.e. an object. What that object is, I do not know (I hoped it would be a an `ADODB.Recordset` but no go).

Comment: Sweet, that helps a lot; I can at least find the number of attachments by parsing the string.  And I might be able to get the raw contents using a different query, but that's a separate task anyway...

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.access-freak.com/tutorials.html#Tutorial07 for some information although he doesn't have a good screenshot or SQL of the query.   His website isn't the best formatted or readable either.

This assumes you're running the query from inside Access 2007.  If you want to run it via ODBC see http://groups.google.ca/group/microsoft.public.data.odbc/browse_thread/thread/d0ee29cc5e54e0fb

Comment: Microsoft recommending ADO for ACE 2007 complex data, eh? Very interesting ;)

Comment: Interesting that they simply don't support this sort of thing with ODBC.  I believe that's the first instance of that I've seen in Access/JET databases.